# Unable to Enter zero after a decimal Point in Edit Text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, decimalformat

My edit text is not allowing to enter zero after the decimal point. 
user should be allowed to enter input like "123.09" but as soon i entered decimal point zero is not allowed in edit text.

my edit view :

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/getPrincipal_editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:ems="7"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edittextstyle" />
```

my Text listeners :

```
EditText et =null;
et =  (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.getPrincipal_editText);
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,##,###.####");
        df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);

        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,##,###");
        hasFractionalPart = false;
        et.addTextChangedListener(this);



 @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
        {
            hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
            hasFractionalPart = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        try {
            int inilen, endlen;
            inilen = et.getText().length();

            String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
            Number n = df.parse(v);
            int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
            if (hasFractionalPart) {

                et.setText(df.format(n));

            } else {

                et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
            }
            endlen = et.getText().length();
            int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
            if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
                et.setSelection(sel);
            } else {
                // place cursor at the end?
                et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // do nothing?
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // do nothing?
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: why do you have input type as number AND decimalNumber? Can you please describe your assumption in your post?

Comment: i have changed to numberDecimal. my input should allow decimal point

Comment: I guess your `afterTextChanged` needs to be smarter about numbers like 3.0.

Comment: yes. thanks. i found